# Creating sample list of data for a unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to create a unit test for a method that takes an arrayList as an input, and returns a different arrayList as an output.

From what I understood about unit testing, I need to make the data then assert that they're correct, but creating an arrayList with sufficient size for the requirements of the method seems complicated.

method to be tested

```
public static List<String> processList(List<String> input){
    //process array
    return new ArrayList<String>();//return new list with new/modded data
}
```

I can do something like

```
ArrayList<String> inputList = new ArrayList();
inputList.add("data1");
...
inputList.add("data30");
```

or make some code that generates a fake array

```
for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
   inputList.add("data"+i);//actual code will be slightly more complicated
}
```

But I would need a few lines for some calculation and variety as the data isn't as simple as I make it appear in this question.

The first solution will take lots of space, the second seems like it will require testing itself, therefore defeating the purpose of a unit test.

I was also thinking of saving the array elements in a text file accessible by the project, and for every input type, I will access the required text file and convert the lines to an array.

Basically, how do I create several arrays of around 10-30 elements each to a unit test a single method that takes a single array input without making a mess?

Comment: You can put array creation logic to separate test util class. Also if something is hard to test then its code/design smell, can you break down your SUT, can you test individual logical steps that SUT is doing..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want your test to assert multiple inputs then you need to provide the expected outcome for every individual test input. For junit this is usually done using [parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests).

If you're afraid of bloating your test code with test data then encoding your [fixtures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_fixture#Software) into a file can be a good idea, some libraries like [json fixtures](https://github.com/corballis/json-fixtures) might help.

Your question also suggests that you would like to somewhat *generate* the test cases, this is I think close to the concept of [Random testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_testing).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just to make a clarification though, what I want to test isn't a set of input values in an array, the single method I want to test uses a single array as an input, `public static List<String> processList(List<String> input){}`. and I'm not sure how parameterized tests would help with that.

Comment: If you're afraid of bloating your test code with test data then perhaps have a look at how to encode your fixtures into a file? See https://github.com/corballis/json-fixtures

Comment: Wow, this looks like what I want! I'm just worried about adding such libraries to legacy code that might not approve such library use. A question, a work around I did for now is moving the data to text/JSON files that I read manually (created some method where each test simply calls with the ID of the required input data), if I skip this library, is what I did sufficient enough or on the track of this library?

Comment: It is hard to answer your questions without anything more specific, but having fixtures encoded into files is sometimes a good idea, You have to ponder the maintenance burden of managing files vs data inside java code.

Comment: I was just trying to understand the worth of fixtures over typical parsable files, but I think I get your point now, I will try to work on JSON Fixtures once I can, if you have any comments, let me know. I will accept your answer, I'm thankful for your and others' help.

Answer (score 1):

+1 For JUnit's parameterized tests. That seems to do exactly what you want.

Here is an alternative to really answer the direct question, though:

```java
ArrayList<String> inputList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
    "data1",
    ...
    "data30"
));
```

It doesn't save you space but at least it looks more like a list of strings to the reader.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just to make a clarification though, what I want to test isn't a set of input values in an array, the single method I want to test uses a single array as an input, `public static List<String> processList(List<String> input){}`. and I'm not sure how parameterized tests would help with that.

Comment: Parameterized tests will solve your "The first solution will take lots of space" issue, by moving the input to a separate class/file out of view.